# Multi-output regression from two input datasets

Tags: python, statistics, regression, linear-regression, lasso-regression

Is it possible to regress a dataset `Y` from two datasets `X1` and `X2`, if all 
`X1`, `X2` and `Y` are matrices. So, it's a multi-output regression problem.

```
x1_train, x1_test, x2_train, x2_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x1, x2, y, test_size=0.2)
Lasso_Regr = Lasso(alpha=0.05, normalize=True)
Lasso_Regr.fit([x1_train, x2_train], y_train)
y_pred = Lasso_Regr.predict([x1_test, x2_test])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.*
```

[image: X1, X2 and Y looks like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is misleading if you split the predictors of training set separately, as the mapping between two predictors is necessary for an accurate prediction.
2. Since you have importing a csv, first transform it to get it to vertical format, convert to a data frame and do the analysis as below.

EDITED:
Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from itertools import izip
from sklearn import linear_model, model_selection

a = izip(*csv.reader(open("input.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb")).writerows(a)
df = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
print(df)

x = df[['x1', 'x2', 'x3']]
y = df['y']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
Lasso_Regr = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.05, normalize=True)
Lasso_Regr.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = Lasso_Regr.predict(x_test)
print y_pred
```

You can add any number of predictors.

Comment: "Convert the matrix to a data frame using pd.DataFrame(matrix_name)" - Which matrix? I have two matrices X1 and X2. Do you mean I should stack them together and convert it into a dataframe?

Comment: You mean is that an array? eg: `x1 = [1,2,3,4,5]` Then, Yes. Try something using like `np.concatenate((x1, x2.T), axis=1)`

Comment: edited my question to show you a screenshot of my data. My X1, X2 and Y looks like this. They are pandas dataframes.

Comment: There I can't see any variable called x1, x2 or y. Did you all the variables in column 1 are predictors except one for y? i.e. want to fit a multiple linear regression model?

Comment: Yes, I want to fit a multiple linear regression model, and a multi-output one, i.e., one row of X1 combined with one row X2 predicts one row of Y. Am I talking sense? Is it possible?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to upload a csv and do analysis. See the edited answer. It will give you the desired answer for sure. Change file names and variable names accordingly.

Comment: Oh, yes, definitely. I shall choose your ans as the best one. Thanks a lot.